# iframe keeps on refreshing in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

My site contains an iframe which is loaded in a model it works fine in Chrome, FireFox but it is not working in Internet Explorer 8.

If I add the URL which is loaded in the iframe in trusted sites it works fine. It also works fine if I put the alert in the JavaScript as in the function below. I want to come up with some other solution. Here is the JavaScript that I am using:

```
function OpenRemedySR(RemedyURL, event) {
    $('#hipAgModal').html('');
    $('#hipAgModal').html("<iframe src='" + RemedyURL + "' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>");
    alert('Click OK to View Status');
    $('#hipAgModal').modal().css({
        'width': function () {
            return ($(document).width() * 0.7);
        },
        'height': function () {
            return ($(document).height() * 0.5);
        },
        'top': function () {
            return ('50%');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine from the code for iframe. Make sure, your popup opening method (OpenRemedySR) is not called more than once.

Comment: `.modal()` - What extension  are you using? It may be the problem.

Comment: got it its a bad practice but does it make any difference?

Comment: @popnoodles using bootstrap modal

Comment: Parkash Kumar i have check this but only iframe load multiple time not the OpenRemedySR function. tell me how to stop iframe after 1 time loading?